# Add view to interactive matplotlib plot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, interactive

I'm using an interactive matplotlib (v3.0.3) plot within a jupyter notebook to map a geopandas geodataframe:

```
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

# shp_aoi = local shapefile
gdf_aoi = geopandas.read_file(shp_aoi)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
gdf_aoi.plot(edgecolor='k', ax=ax)
```

[image: Interactive Figure 1 Result]

The interactive toolbar is useful to zoom and then move back to a previous view (left arrow), but I'd like to provide the user with a preset zoomed in view in addition to this original full extent view. Outside of an interactive notebook I would use the axis set_xlim() and set_ylim() to limit the extent and zoom to a subset of that map for a second plot:

```
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)
gdf_aoi.plot(edgecolor='k', ax=ax)
```

I'm wondering if I can generate the plot as in the first code snippet and somehow add a view to it so the user could easily switch back and forth (using the left and right arrows on the interactive map)?

Comment: You question is kind of confusing but if you're open to suggestions you should try [`bokeh`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide.html)`.

Comment: @JayPatel I added an example image of the interactive map to hopefully relate the 'view' navigation I'm trying to describe. Anything I can add or clarify to make my question clearer?